# Designing Better Maps

Tags: cartography, design

Using this chart, enhanced my presentations and presentation skills:
[image: Extreme Presentation Method - Ten Steps to Persuasive Presentation] found on [Extreme Presentation Method](http://www.extremepresentation.com/).

How would you modify this chart to be directly related to map design?

Comment: This question needs rephrasing - it isn't clear. The graph needs urgent resizing or a better link leading directly to the graph discussed.

Comment: link to the image in full res: http://www.extremepresentation.com/uploads/images/3_Extreme_Presentation_Method.jpg

Comment: @Marinheiro - @jonatr - I have imgur blocked at work, so I can't even see the image

Comment: measurement - how did the chart enhance your presentations? What type of presentations? Maps in powerpoint are often only for display or asthetics (no zooming or touching). The process I see in the chart seems to lead me to apply the same to a presentation with maps. OK while talking I got a clue and re-read your post. INSTEAD of making a presentation, apply this to making maps. OK I will look at that.

Comment: @Brad Nesom - I wasn't referring to maps in PowerPoint, rather map design in general.

Comment: I think the question needs rephrasing as the first sentence is a little unclear. Also, a presentation has a somewhat standard structure (presenter and audience). The usage of maps is a lot more broad. Could you narrow it down to some specific instances of map usage?

Comment: @jonatr If your using google chrome; right click the image and "Open image in new tab" or on Firefox use "View Image" to get the full resolution.

Comment: @SaultDon , most of the work places in my country (including mine) have only IE, and on it the pic wasn't showing (but it has been fixed since).

Answer (score 1):

This question is in an interesting area: deconstructing map design. Here is my answer to the 10 points:

- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10 apply equally to maps
- 6, 7 and 8 can be replaced by 
  'what layers will you use', 
  'what is your scale of interest', 
  'what is the best way of presenting your spatial data; thematic map, points, polygons'

but I don't think its the most interesting way to frame the question.  How about
'in terms of map usability, what is(are) your pet hate(s)?' to which my answer is 
'using flashy overly clever design elements in maps which don't meet the needs of the user e.g. BBC election map http://googleearthdesign.blogspot.com/2010/04/uk-election-map-triumph-of-style-over.html'